# C# code in JQuery in ASP.NET razor view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a server-side model with a datetime type field ***PublishDate***. I am sending `List<Posts>` as json in response to ajax call.

I would like to use c# code `Convert.ToDateTime(this.PublishDate).ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")` in jquery code. Below is my code what I tried so far-

```
var posts = response.Posts;
$.each(posts, function () {
  $('#container').append('<div class="row"> 
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                              <h2>' + this.PostTitle + '</h2>
                              <span>Published on: @Convert.ToDateTime(this.PublishDate).ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")</span></div></div>');
});
```

But it's not working. Any idea?

Comment: What is the type of property `PublishDate`?

Comment: Where do you place the jquery code because you're trying to combine Razor and jquery

Comment: why is javascript date formatting out of the question? there are libraries designed to help tackle this specific problem, like moment.js

Comment: You dont need `Convert.ToDateTime()` if its already a `DateTime` - just `@PublishDate.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")` but this does not make a lot of sense since razor code is parsed on the server. Is this part of an ajax callback?

Comment: If this is an ajax callback, why not just format the date in the controller method?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of using Razor is that you can use the power of C# in your html code, or cshtml to be more precise.

Assuming your div id is `container`, you can do this.

You have a member in your model class named `PublishDate`

Add this in HTML

```
<input id="container" name="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PublishDate)" value="@DateTime.PublishDate.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")">
```

And remove the coversion from jQuery.

Comment: In this case it looks like we're dealing with a javascript object gotten from an action method somewhere else.
You might want to give the object a property with the properly formatted value for publishdate *before* you render it to the page.
This is why viewmodels are a good idea.

Comment: Indeed, just picked up http://knockoutjs.com/. MVVM is really the way to go for modern interactive web dev.

Comment: A `<div>` does not have a `value` attribute!

Comment: Oops yes, I had an input tag converted it to div for example

Comment: OP wanted a div, but this has nothing to do with OP's question anyway - which is generating the markup dynamically in jquery - and you cant use razor code to do that because the razor code is parsed on the server

Answer (score 1):

It could be, worked for me.
Try this format:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(PublishDate, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't interuse C# and jquery code in this way, for the simple reason that the C# code is executed server side, before the data is sent to the page.

The code that says `@Convert.ToDateTime(this.PublishDate)` looks for a property called `PublishDate` on the class that renders the razor page and tries to convert it to a `DateTime` object.

One way to do what you're looking for, is to add a property to your model that has the properly formatted date in it already, so you don't have to bother with parsing it using Javascript.

Another is to parse it with javascript anyway.
Because date/time objects are complex and tricky things and can trouble your day with cross browser quirks, using a library to make your life easier is recommendable.
A good place to start would be [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

which would look something like this :

```
'<span> Published on: ' + moment(this.PublishDate).format('MMM dd , yyyy') +  ' </span></div></div>'
```

Comment: Bonus points if you drop javascript string concatenation all together and use a templating engine ;)